# How to convert json to normal object?

Tags: java, json

An array of strings is stored in al arraylist which is in JSON format. Now i want to Convert that arraylist into normal object. How do i convert it?

```
public class Json {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    al.add(1);
    al.add("Lokesh");
    al.add("Gupta");
    al.add(Arrays.asList("ADMIN", "MANAGER"));

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(al));
}}
```

Comment: What language are you programming in? I guess it's C#'ish but i'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

Create an Object with your attributes,
eg:-

```
public class User {
    Integer id;
    String firstName,
    String lastName;
    List<Role> roles;// Where roles is a list of another Object Role
    //getter and setter methods
}
```

Then,

```
    public class Manager{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String json = "{'id':1,'firstName':'Deva','lastName':'Raj','roles':['ADMIN','MANAGER']}";
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            User user = gson.fromJson(json, User.class);
            System.out.println(user);
        }
    }
```