# How to covert json to normal object?

Tags: json

```
public class Json {
public static void main(String[] args) {

   Json obj=new  Json();
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    al.add(1);
    al.add("Lokesh");e
    al.add("Gupta");
    al.add(Arrays.asList("ADMIN", "MANAGER"));

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(al));


   System.out.println(
            gson.fromJson("{'id':1,'firstName':'Deva','lastName':'Raj','roles':['ADMIN','MANAGER']}",
                    Json.class));
}}
```

**output** is:

```
[1,"Lokesh","Gupta",["ADMIN","MANAGER"]]
Json@6a30c7
```

Comment: reply fast man...tanq in adavance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913099/how-to-convert-json-to-normal-object

Why are u asking same questions

Comment: in my same class..how to get json and normal object output?

Comment: this should help  u out (i am assuming u are using java) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395551/convert-a-json-string-to-object-in-java